# Echarts- How do i convert this example to React (circle packing in js -> react_

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, echarts

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=circle-packing-with-d3
I need to convert this example into React.

I have data in format

```
children: [ name: x1, children: []],
value}
nested
```

thanks